# In my pc DELL LATITUDE 7490 ubantu just freezes

Tags: 22.04, freeze

I have DELL LATITUDE 7490 and I want to use gazebo(a robotics simulation software) hence I planned and opted duel boot for my PC (one windows 11 and another ubantu20.04.05). I installed ubantu 20.04 since starting of this year but it just freezed while i am working on it. I bared it for a while and my work was done.But now in MAY i again need gazebo so i deleted ubantu20.04 and tried fresh installation but that also it just freezes and even didn't allowed me to finish installation. So I opted for 22.04 and same happened for it as well until after 10 or so tries i was finally able to install ubantu 22.04 and as i started to work on this very fresh installed OS it froze again and as it freezes i only have one option just to power shout down my device and restart it.

It's really annoying as i am unable to work and my time is getting wasted, please help me out with this.

This is my system detais if it helps.

[image]

Comment: This is vague with little details; if installation fails to complete (*you weren't specific as to product or how long it freezes & what exactly does that mean; was SysRq commands not responding, just a GUI freeze? thus terminal worked for exploration + SysRq being possible*) it's usually related to media so did you verify ISO & validate media?  On installed systems again no clues as to if it's only GUI that freezes, the terminal was still working or SysRq was possible? Did you boot *live* media & explore systemd journals for clues on 'freeze'? Did you do any exploration as you don't mention it

Comment: Thank you for addressing, here freezing is meant by complete freezing, nothing can be done or open after that. Once while addressing this issue I was using ttyl (as I thought if there is issue in gui then it ttyl will not be affected and I might be able to find the cause) but it still froze there and considering time then till I keep it on, it's frozen. So after it freezes there is no room for exploration and nothing can be done. Yes if it freezes when an audio is being played then a perticular section of that audio keeps on repeating but again nothing can be done.

Comment: If the screen refresh has *frozen* then you may not see the effect of switching to text terminal (tty) which is why I mentioned SysRq commands... They bypass any UI (text or GUI) & allow you to command the kernel directly.. and you can usually detect from the hardware itself if it's responding (*disk activity LEDs etc or sounds if using spinning-rust drives etc*) which is why I mentioned it (ie. useful even on headless devices). You didn't specify what 22.04 product/release you're using, if you tried various stack/kernels (5.15 (GA), 5.19 (HWE) & 6.2 (edge) are available) etc.

Comment: Thank you addressing once again, I didn't knew about SysRq commands well after being tired of this issue I changed my pc itself and now this new pc of mine is working smoothly as of now, as the best my knowledge it 5.14 was the kernel version. Ane kernal used to show me ACPI BIOS errors as followed "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [PR. PROD. CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20216730/psargs-330)
[ 0.511813] ACPI Error: Aborting method PR.PRO1. CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)". I tried all steps which I found on a community qna which includes firmware update.